# MSP 2010 - duplicating tasks and logic

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I have a schedule I am putting together for a repeating layout multi-floor building.  Is there any easy way to copy the tasks and their predecessors and successors from say floor 2 and with minor renaming and editing and use them for floors 3-6?

I've tried copying and pasting small batches of tasks, 6-8 at a time, and the logic within the task range updates with the new relative Task IDs, predecessors and successors outside of the copied task range stay the same, which is great but I am seeing other inconsistencies in the pasted task logic that has me wondering if I am missing something or maybe there is a better way to do this (short of using sub-projects for each floor).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a summary task for floor one indenting all of the work underneath.  Collapse the summary task - copy and paste.  The links between the subtasks should be retained.  What inconsistencies are you seeing?

Comment: Julie, thanks for the response.  It is odd that this works perfectly while doing a multi-select copy and paste of multiple standalone tasks resulted in missing or dropped predecessor/successors and other inconsistencies.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say "odd".  Summary tasks and subtasks have a sort of relationship.  For example, delete, copy, or move a summary task and all  of the subtasks are deleted, copied, or moved as well.  The indentation under the summary tasks is more than for just looks. :-)